# Does a vegan diet have negative/positive effect on athletes?

Tags: veganism, sports

I often hear that vegan athletes cannot perform at the same level as non-vegan athletes, focused more in terms of strength, performance, etc.

[There](http://www.runnersworld.com/fuel-school/do-endurance-athletes-need-meat-to-perform-well) are [tons](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2012/jul/30/lizzie-armitstead-vegetarian-athletes-olympics-2012) of [articles](https://blog.bulletproof.com/carl-lewis-vegan/) and [debates](https://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/06/20/can-athletes-perform-well-on-a-vegan-diet/?_r=0) on [the](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/health-and-fitness/health/can-vegan-athletes-still-build-muscle-and-compete-in-sports/article20945720/) topic.

But is there a real study or good examples that support this?

And, if any, **what are the pros/cons for athletes on becoming vegan/vegetarian**?

Comment: In what way? If the premise of your question is "there is tons of arguments and debates", it is already too broad to answer in this context. But if you have a very specific question about a particular aspect of how a vegan diet might affect the body, it might work here; but this is simply too broad to answer decisively in the one-answer Q&A style of this site.

Comment: `is there a real study or good examples that support this?` so, no @RobertCartaino, I'm looking for studies and facts, I don't want more debate as there is enough already on the internet

Comment: About *what* though? There's no real "problem statement" here that can be answered definitively in the context of this site. "Performance" can mean anything; the field of *athletes* covers a ***lot*** of territory. We could list literally thousands of anecdotes about performance improvements here they'd all be equally valid. That's why broad questions generating a scattershot of random answers for your to pick through later are not really how this site was meant to work. ("Ask about *real* problems you actually face." — the [Stack Exchange Tour](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tour))